# Is recursive callback with closure safe?

Tags: vb.net, closures

I want to know if I do something like this:

```
   Private CurrentASyncSerialNumber As Integer  ' Break the callback chain if it isn't totally dean
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
          If tmrNoSerialActivity.ElapsedTime > 2 Then
             CurrentASyncSerialNumber += 1
             RunASyncComms(0, CurrentASyncSerialNumber)
          End If
       End Sub



Private Sub RunASyncComms(State As Integer, SerialNumber As Integer)
   if SerialNumber<>CurrentASyncSerialNumber then return
   tmrNoSerialActivity.ResetTimer 
   select case State 
       case 0    

         ' Some aync code involving RS232
          RS232_AddCommand(Sub() RunASyncComms(1000, SerialNumber))
      case 1000:
         ' Some aync code involving RS232
          RS232_AddCommand(Sub() RunASyncComms(2000, SerialNumber))
      case 2000:
         ' Some aync code involving RS232,
          RS232_AddCommand(Sub() RunASyncComms(0, SerialNumber))
          ' And now we start over.
```

The function RS232_AddCommand is similar to BeginInvoke, except that it doesn't fire the next command until all timer and paint events are done, and also makes sure the former RS232 async code has completed.

My question is this line that recursively calls it "RS232_AddCommand(Sub() RunASyncComms(1000, SerialNumber))".  Will that create a closure chain that accumulates and never gets collected by garbage collection?  Since it gets added to a collection and delayed on its run, am I safe doing this?  Or will I get even worse with an eventual stack overflow.

I want to know if my code is safe.

Comment: I should mention that RS232_AddCommand adds to a list, and I have a timer when run, pulls at item off this list if RS232 isn't marked as busy.  If it is marked as busy, then then when RS232 data comes in and the final byte is received, then after running a callback to handle the data received, I turn off RS232Busy so the timer can run the next call.  This means recursive calls to "RunASyncComms" are always fired by a system.windows.forms.timer and are delayed.

Comment: Watching the task manager, memory is increasing quite fast, but when I put in a button that performs a "GC.Collect", it takes a long time before any activity occurs.  It appears that this is leaving a lot of garbage behind, but garbage collection will eventually get it.  It also appears GC.Collect doesn't reduce memory usage as reported by task manager, but simply takes a long time before it starts using memory.  It also never gets above 10Meg for memory usage.